# I've been trying to run a code in MPLAB for interfacing a finger print scanner with PIC16F877A and LCD but the code is giving errors

Tags: pic, mplab-x

Here is the code

```c
#define _XTAL_FREQ 18432000


#include <xc.h>

#include<pic.h>

#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>


// BEGIN CONFIG

#pragma config FOSC = HS // Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator)

#pragma config WDTE = OFF // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT enabled)

#pragma config PWRTE = OFF // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)

#pragma config BOREN = ON // Brown-out Reset Enable bit (BOR enabled)

#pragma config LVP = OFF // Low-Voltage (Single-Supply) In-Circuit Serial Programming Enable bit (RB3 is digital I/O, HV on MCLR must be used for programming)

#pragma config CPD = OFF // Data EEPROM Memory Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM code protection off)

#pragma config WRT = OFF // Flash Program Memory Write Enable bits (Write protection off; all program memory may be written to by EECON control)

#pragma config CP = OFF // Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit (Code protection off)

//END CONFIG


#define uchar unsigned char

#define uint unsigned int


#define LCDPORTDIR TRISA

#define LCDPORT PORTA

#define RS RE1

#define EN RE0


#define SWPORTdir TRISD

#define SWPORT PORTD

#define enrol RD4

#define match RD5

#define delet RD7


#define ok RD6

#define up RD5

#define down RD4


#define LEDdir TRISC3

#define LED RC3


#define HIGH 1

#define LOW 0


#define PASS 0

#define ERROR 1


#define checkKey(id) id=up<down?++id:down<up?--id:id;


uchar buf[20];

uchar buf1[20];

volatile uint index=0;

volatile int flag=0;

uint msCount=0;

uint g_timerflag=1;

volatile uint count=0;

uchar data[10];

uint id=1;


enum

{

 CMD,

 DATA, 

 SBIT_CREN=4,

 SBIT_TXEN,

 SBIT_SPEN,

};


const char passPack[]={0xEF, 0x1, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x1, 0x0, 0x7, 0x13, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1B};

const char f_detect[]={0xEF, 0x1, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x1, 0x0, 0x3, 0x1, 0x0, 0x5};

const char f_imz2ch1[]={0xEF, 0x1, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x1, 0x0, 0x4, 0x2, 0x1, 0x0, 0x8};

const char f_imz2ch2[]={0xEF, 0x1, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x1, 0x0, 0x4, 0x2, 0x2, 0x0, 0x9};

const char f_createModel[]={0xEF,0x1,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x1,0x0,0x3,0x5,0x0,0x9};

char f_storeModel[]={0xEF,0x1,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x1,0x0,0x6,0x6,0x1,0x0,0x1,0x0,0xE};

const char f_search[]={0xEF, 0x1, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x1, 0x0, 0x8, 0x1B, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xA3, 0x0, 0xC8};

char f_delete[]={0xEF,0x1,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x1,0x0,0x7,0xC,0x0,0x0,0x0,0x1,0x0,0x15};


void lcdwrite(uchar ch,uchar rw)
{

     LCDPORT= ch>>4 & 0x0F;

     RS=rw;

     EN=1;

     __delay_ms(5);

     EN=0; 

     LCDPORT= ch & 0x0F;

     EN=1;

     __delay_ms(5);

     EN=0;    

}


lcdprint(char *str)
{

    while(*str)

    {

        lcdwrite(*str++,DATA);

        //__delay_ms(20);

    }

}


lcdbegin()
{

    uchar lcdcmd[5]={0x02,0x28,0x0E,0x06,0x01};

    uint i=0;

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)

    lcdwrite(lcdcmd[i], CMD);

}


void lcdinst()
{

    lcdwrite(0x80, CMD);

    lcdprint("1-Match 2-Enroll");

    lcdwrite(0xc0, CMD);

    lcdprint("3-delete Finger");

    __delay_ms(10);

}


void serialbegin(uint baudrate)
{

  SPBRG = (18432000UL/(long)(64UL*baudrate))-1;      // baud rate @18.432000Mhz Clock

    TXSTAbits.SYNC = 0;                              //Setting Asynchronous Mode, ie UART

    RCSTAbits.SPEN = 1;                              //Enables Serial Port

    TRISC7 = 1;                                   //As Prescribed in Datasheet

    TRISC6 = 0;                                   //As Prescribed in Datasheet

    RCSTAbits.CREN = 1;                                     //Enables Continuous Reception

    TXSTAbits.TXEN = 1;                                     //Enables Transmission


    GIE  = 1; // ENABLE interrupts

    INTCONbits.PEIE = 1; // ENable peripheral interrupts.

    PIE1bits.RCIE   = 1; // ENABLE USART receive interrupt

    PIE1bits.TXIE   = 0; // disable USART TX interrupt


    PIR1bits.RCIF = 0;

}


void serialwrite(char ch)
{

    while(TXIF==0);  // Wait till the transmitter register becomes empty

    TXIF=0;          // Clear transmitter flag

    TXREG=ch;        // load the char to be transmitted into transmit reg

}


serialprint(char *str)
{

    while(*str)

    {

        serialwrite(*str++);

    }

}


void interrupt SerialRxPinInterrupt(void)
{

    if((PIR1bits.RCIF == 1) && (PIE1bits.RCIE == 1))

    {
        uchar ch=RCREG; 

        buf[index++]=ch;

        if(index>0)

            flag=1;

        RCIF = 0; // clear rx flag

    }  

}


void serialFlush()
{

    for(int i=0;i<sizeof(buf);i++)

    {

        buf[i]=0;

    }

}


int sendcmd2fp(char *pack, int len)
{

  uint res=ERROR;

  serialFlush();

  index=0;

  __delay_ms(100);

  for(int i=0;i<len;i++)

  {

    serialwrite(*(pack+i));

  }

  __delay_ms(1000);

  if(flag == 1)

  {

    if(buf[0] == 0xEF && buf[1] == 0x01)

    {

        if(buf[6] == 0x07)   // ack

        {

        if(buf[9] == 0)
        {
            uint data_len= buf[7];

            data_len<<=8;

            data_len|=buf[8];

            for(int i=0;i<data_len;i++)

                data[i]=0;

            for(int i=0;i<data_len-2;i++)

            {

                data[i]=buf[10+i];

            }

            res=PASS;

        }


        else
        {

         res=ERROR;

        }

        }

    }

    index=0;

    flag=0

   return res;

}

}
uint getId()

{

    uint id=0;

    lcdwrite(1, CMD);

    while(1)

    {

        lcdwrite(0x80, CMD);

        checkKey(id);

        sprintf(buf1,"Enter Id:%d  ",id);

        lcdprint(buf1);

        __delay_ms(200);

        if(ok == LOW)

            return id;

    }

}

void matchFinger()
{

      lcdwrite(1,CMD);

      lcdprint("Place Finger"); 

      lcdwrite(192,CMD);

      __delay_ms(2000);

     if(!sendcmd2fp(&f_detect[0],sizeof(f_detect)))
     {
         if(!sendcmd2fp(&f_imz2ch1[0],sizeof(f_imz2ch1)))
         {

            if(!sendcmd2fp(&f_search[0],sizeof(f_search)))
            {

                lcdwrite(1,CMD);

                lcdprint("Finger Found");

                uint id= data[0];

                     id<<=8;

                     id+=data[1];

                uint score=data[2];

                        score<<=8;

                        score+=data[3];

                sprintf(buf1,"Id:%d  Score:%d",id,score);

                lcdwrite(192,CMD);

                lcdprint(buf1); 

                LED=1;

                __delay_ms(1000);

                LED=0;

            }
            else
            {

                lcdwrite(1,CMD);

                lcdprint("Not Found");

            }

         }

     }
     else
     {

         lcdprint("No Finger"); 

     }

      __delay_ms(2000);

}

void enrolFinger(
{

     lcdwrite(1,CMD);

     lcdprint("Enroll Finger");

     __delay_ms(2000);

     lcdwrite(1,CMD);

     lcdprint("Place Finger"); 

     lcdwrite(192,CMD);

      __delay_ms(1000);

     if(!sendcmd2fp(&f_detect[0],sizeof(f_detect)))
     {

        if(!sendcmd2fp(&f_imz2ch1[0],sizeof(f_imz2ch1)))
        {

            lcdprint("Finger Detected");

            __delay_ms(1000);

            lcdwrite(1,CMD);

            lcdprint("Place Finger");

            lcdwrite(192,CMD);

            lcdprint("    Again   "); 

            __delay_ms(2000);

            if(!sendcmd2fp(&f_detect[0],sizeof(f_detect)))
            {
                if(!sendcmd2fp(&f_imz2ch2[0],sizeof(f_imz2ch2)))
                {

                    lcdwrite(1,CMD);

                    lcdprint("Finger Detected");

                    __delay_ms(1000);

                    if(!sendcmd2fp(&f_createModel[0],sizeof(f_createModel)))
                    {

                        id=getId();

                        f_storeModel[11]= (id>>8) & 0xff;

                        f_storeModel[12]= id & 0xff;

                        f_storeModel[14]= 14+id; 

                       if(!sendcmd2fp(&f_storeModel[0],sizeof(f_storeModel)))
                       {

                            lcdwrite(1,CMD);

                            lcdprint("Finger Stored");

                            sprintf(buf1,"Id:%d",id);

                            lcdwrite(192,CMD);

                            lcdprint(buf1);

                            __delay_ms(1000);

                       }
                       else
                       {
                            lcdwrite(1,CMD);

                            lcdprint("Finger Not Stored");
                       }
                    }
                    else
                        lcdprint("Error");
                }
                else
                   lcdprint("Error");  
            }
            else
                lcdprint("No Finger"); 
        } 
     }
     else
     {
         lcdprint("No Finger"); 
     }

      __delay_ms(2000);

}

void deleteFinger()
{

    id=getId();

   f_delete[10]=id>>8 & 0xff;

   f_delete[11]=id & 0xff;

   f_delete[14]=(21+id)>>8 & 0xff;

   f_delete[15]=(21+id) & 0xff;

   if(!sendcmd2fp(&f_delete[0],sizeof(f_delete)))
  {
     lcdwrite(1,CMD);

     sprintf(buf1,"Finger ID %d ",id);

     lcdprint(buf1);

     lcdwrite(192, CMD);

     lcdprint("Deleted Success");

  }
   else
   {
       lcdwrite(1,CMD);

       lcdprint("Error");
   }

   __delay_ms(2000);

}

      
int main()
{            

  void (*FP)();  

  ADCON1=0b00000110;

  LEDdir= 0;

  SWPORTdir=0xF0;

  SWPORT=0x0F;

  serialbegin(57600);

  LCDPORTDIR=0x00;

  TRISE=0;

  lcdbegin();

  lcdprint("Fingerprint");

  lcdwrite(192,CMD);

  lcdprint("Interfacing");

  __delay_ms(2000);

  lcdwrite(1,CMD);

  lcdprint("Using PIC16F877A");

  lcdwrite(192,CMD);

  lcdprint("Circuit Digest");

  __delay_ms(2000);

  index=0;    

  while(sendcmd2fp(&passPack[0],sizeof(passPack)))
  {

     lcdwrite(1,CMD);

     lcdprint("FP Not Found");

     __delay_ms(2000);

     index=0;

  }

  lcdwrite(1,CMD);

  lcdprint("FP Found");

  __delay_ms(1000);

  lcdinst();

  while(1)
  { 

    FP=match<enrol?matchFinger:enrol<delet?enrolFinger:delet<enrol?deleteFinger:lcdinst;

    FP();

  } 

  return 0;

}
```

The code is suppose to interface the PIC16F877A with LCD and fingerprint scanner for proteus simulation but the code seems to be having an error that I can't figure out when running it on MPLAB

Comment: You're supposed to add error information @KaylorKgomotso.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)